# refresh data after an insert with tkinter, python

Tags: python, tkinter

newbie here, im afraid too new to even search properly about it.

i made a gui in tkinter to enter people extra hours and display last registers as i was asked to do. (we had a excel file to do it but it was giving too much trouble)

[it looks like this]

[image: 1]

what i want to add now is that, when an entry is added (1) the table shown is refreshed inmediatly after (2) as a way to check the last entry.
but i have no idea how! been searching a while and i couldnt figure it out...

code looks like this

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
from tkcalendar import *
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy
from datetime import datetime

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};''Server=RCL-SUP034\SQLXLAB;''Database=Marcaciones;''username=admin;''password:admin;')
cursor = conn.cursor() 

root = Tk()
root.title("Carga de horas extras")
root.geometry("780x600")
root.resizable(False,False)

cal = Calendar(root, locale='en_US', date_pattern='dd.mm.y',selectmode="day", year=2021)
cal.place(x=330, y=50)

def obtener_fecha():
    my_label.config(text=cal.get_date())

boton_calendario = ttk.Button(root, text="Seleccionar Fecha", command=obtener_fecha)
boton_calendario.place(x=150 ,y=50)
my_label = Label(root, text="")
my_label.place(x=165 ,y=82)

codigo_entry = Entry(root, width=20)
codigo_entry.place(x=115, y=10) # OK
lista_desplegable = ttk.Combobox(root,width=10, state="readonly")
lista_desplegable.place(x= 290, y=10)
horas_opcion = [0,0.50,1,1.50,2,2.50,3,3.50,4,4.50,5,5.50,6,6.50,7,7.50,8,8.50,9,9.50,9.99]
lista_desplegable['values']=horas_opcion

codigo_entry_label = Label(root, text="Codigo Trabajador").place(height=20, width=100, x= 10,y=10) # OK
horas_entry_label = Label(root, text="Horas extras")
horas_entry_label.place(height=20, width=75, x= 200,y=10) # OK


insert_hhee = '''INSERT INTO tbl_marcas (codigo,fecha,hhee)  VALUES (?,?,?)''' 
consulta_horas= '''SELECT top 10 codigo, operario, hhee, fecha FROM registros where hhee <> 0 order by id desc'''
todos_operarios = '''SELECT codigo from tbl_operarios'''
respaldo_hhee = '''EXEC tabla_respaldo'''

def agrega_cal():
        cursor.execute(insert_hhee, (codigo_entry.get(),cal.get_date(), lista_desplegable.get()))
        conn.commit()
        codigo_entry.delete(0, END)
        refresco()

def respaldo():
    try:
        validacion = messagebox.askyesno(message="Se respaldaran todos los datos ingresados a la fecha",title="respaldo")
        if validacion == True:
            cursor.execute(respaldo_hhee)
            conn.commit()
            messagebox.showinfo(message="Respaldo exitoso")
        else:
            messagebox.showerror(message="Respaldo cancelado", title="aviso")
    except:
        messagebox.showerror(message="Respaldo cancelado", title="aviso")

agrega_cal_boton = ttk.Button(root, text="Agregar registro", command=agrega_cal).place(height=30, width=105, x=15 ,y=50)
respaldo_boton = ttk.Button(root, text="Respaldar datos",command=respaldo).place(height=30, width=110, x=620,y=10)


frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Ultimos registros con horas extras")
frame1.place(height=200, width=750, rely=0.40, relx=0)

df1 = pd.read_sql_query(consulta_horas, conn)
tv1 = ttk.Treeview(frame1)
tv1.place(relheight=1, relwidth=1)
treescrolly = tk.Scrollbar(frame1, orient="vertical", command=tv1.yview)
treescrollx = tk.Scrollbar(frame1, orient="horizontal", command=tv1.xview)
tv1.configure(yscrollcommand=treescrolly.set)
treescrollx.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
treescrolly.pack(side="right", fill="y")
tv1["column"] = list(df1.columns)
tv1["show"] = "headings"
for column in tv1["columns"]:
    tv1.heading(column, text=column)
df_rows = df1.to_numpy().tolist()
for row in df_rows:
    tv1.insert("", "end",values=row)
    
s = ttk.Style(root)
s.theme_use('clam')
root.mainloop()
```

no idea how to refresh data shown it tbh

btw i know the very basics of python.. im aware my path has just begun :d

Comment: i did google, i applied many possible solutions to it and they didnt work for me. thats why im asking for help. im not asking for you guys to do my work i just need some hints.

Comment: That `refresco()` command is missing and seems the function that should do what you want. Could you add it?

Comment: In addition, it makes sense to use english language in code to make it easier for others to read your code. Especially if you need help with.

Comment: oh that is an in progress function, i guess i have to throw the query again but still trying to figure it out. it looked like this
def refresco():
 cursor.execute(consulta_horas)
 conn.commit()
but at this point im just throwin blind punches... about the language, you are right...gonna try to change it from now on! thanks